# Estimate lower bound of a function

Tags: calculus

Let us consider a function $f(x)=\sqrt{4A+4Bx+C(1-e^{2x})}$. It has provided that $x\leq 0, A\geq 0$ and $2B\geq C>0$. Also, it has given that $f$ is increasing for $x\leq0$. Is it possible to find any lower bound other than $0$  i.e. $f(x)\geq C$ for $C\neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x) \to i \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ for all values of $A$, $B$ and $C$ that satisfy your constraints. Therefore, no lower bound is possible since the image of the function is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is not possible to find a constant such that $f(x)>C$. But is the any estimation such that $f(x)>g(x)$?

Comment: I mean, it depends on how you want to define ">". Usually, we don't use ">" when dealing with complex numbers.